# Powershell : get unique permissions for folder and apply each to function

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that fetches the permissions for a folder, then select only unique IdentityReference and then it attempts to apply a simple function to it. however, for some reason its not working.

My script

```
function display_perm {
    param([String] $p)

    Write-Output $p

}

$acl = $(Get-Acl "folderpath").Access 

# Method 1 
$perm = $acl | select -Unique IdentityReference | %{ display_perm $_ }
#write-output $perm
# Method 2
foreach($p in $perm) { display_perm $p }
```

I tried two different approach, method one doesn't output anything on its own only when I do a write-output a second time it outputs:

```
@{IdentityReference=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM}
@{IdentityReference=BUILTIN\Administrators}
@{IdentityReference=COMP1234\PCUser}
```

method 2 does output the same as above but one at a time.

What I want is to pass individual Identity References via a pipeline or even foreach would be fine but I don't understand what this @{} stuff is maybe it means object but how do I get the following output:

```
Permission 1 : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Permission 2 : BUILTIN\Administrators
Permission 3 : COMP1234\PCUser
```

I want to pass the permission string to the function and display it as a string as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `@{IdentityReference=...}` means that you're displaying an object (it's PowerShell's string representation of an object).

To get just the value of an identity reference you need to expand the property. Twice.

```
$acl |
  Select-Object -Unique -Expand IdentityReference |
  Select-Object -Expand value
```

If you want the identity references in a numbered list you'd need to pass the already formatted string into your function `display_perm()`, like this:

```
$i = 1
$acl |
  Select-Object -Unique -Expand IdentityReference |
  ForEach-Object { display_perm ('Permission {0} : {1}' -f $i++, $_.value) }
```

or like this:

```
$perm = $acl |
        Select-Object -Unique -Expand IdentityReference |
        Select-Object -Expand value

$i = 1
foreach($p in $perm) {
  display_perm ('Permission {0} : {1}' -f $i++, $p)
}
```

It'd be better to handle the entire output in your output function:

```
function Write-IdentityReference {
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity[]]$Acl
  )

  Begin {
    $formatString = 'Permission {0} : {1}'
  }

  Process {
    $Acl | ForEach-Object {
      $i = 1
      $_.Access |
        Select-Object -Unique -Expand IdentityReference |
        ForEach-Object { $formatString -f $i++, $_.value }
    }
  }
}

Get-Acl 'C:\some\folder' | Write-IdentityReference
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is forcing whatever you are passing into it to be string because of this:

```
 param([String] $p)
```

which means it is passing a string back, drop that and it will pass a FileSystemAccessRule object back:

```
function display_perm {
param($p)

    Write-Output $p

}

$acl = $(Get-Acl c:\temp).Access 

# Method 1 
$acl | select -Unique IdentityReference | %{ display_perm $_ } 

# Method 2
foreach($p in $acl) { display_perm $p.IdentityReference }
```

Another option would be to move the processing into the function and just pass the path to the function:

```
function display_perm {
    param(
        [string]$path
    )

        $acl = Get-acl $path

        $acl.Access | select -Unique IdentityReference 

}

display_perm 'c:\temp'
```

Comment: Value                 
-----                 
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM   
BUILTIN\Administrators, how do I get rid of Value ----- and just display individual values

Comment: You would need to reference the value, you can change the last line to:`(display_perm 'c:\temp' ).IdentityReference.Value`